# Picker selected item showing class name at zero position

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, picker, xamarin.uwp

I am using picker in my xaml like

```
    <Picker x:Name="pickerService" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding ServiceName}"/>
```

My Service class is like

```
    public class Service
    {
      [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
      public int Id { get; set; }
      public string ServiceName { get; set; }
    }
```

and adding list to picker itemssource like

```
    List<Service> serviceNames = new List<Service>();
    serviceNames = App.DAUtil.GetServices ();
    pickerService.ItemsSource = serviceNames ;
```

here I am getting serviceNames list from my local db.When I select a service from picker sometimes it is showing class name at zero position instead of "ServiceName", like "App.MainPage". Please help me to solve this.

Comment: Which file you have `picker` app.xaml class or Main.xaml?

Comment: Hi @r15 in Main.xaml

Comment: I can't see any error in your code. Can you edit your question and post full .cs and xaml code.

Comment: What is the version of your Xamarin.Forms . I could not reproduce the issue .You can share a demo so that I can test it on my side.

Comment: Hi @LucasZhang-MSFT I am using 3.1.0 version

Comment: Update it to 4.x .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT please check my question now.

Comment: @r15 please check my question now.

Comment: Share your sample so that I can test it on my side .